# How do I return a message after submitting a form on my page with PHP?

Tags: php, html, forms, input, contacts

I just followed [this tutorial](http://tangledindesign.com/how-to-create-a-contact-form-using-html5-css3-and-php/) on how to create a contact form with PHP. Now everything works fine but when I submit a form it returns a message on a new blank page. I want this to happen on the current page underneath the contact form.

This is my first time ever doing anything with PHP so I have no idea how I would do this. In the tutorial it is briefly mentioned that you can just put the script anywhere you would want the message to appear but it doesn't seem to work for me.

This is my HTML code:

```
<form method="post" action="contact.php">
          <label>Name</label>
          <input name="name" placeholder="John Doe">

          <label>Email</label>
          <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="john@doe.com">

          <label>Message</label>
          <textarea name="message" placeholder="Hello..."></textarea>

          <label id="antispam">What is 2+2? (Anti-spam)</label>
          <input id="antispambox" name="human" placeholder="4">

          <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
```

and this is my PHP code:

```
<?php
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $from = 'From: TangledDemo';
    $to = 'contact@tangledindesign.com';
    $subject = 'Hello';
    $human = $_POST['human'];

    $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

    if ($_POST['submit']) {
        if ($name != '' && $email != '') {
            if ($human == '4') {
                if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {
                    echo '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>';
                } else {
                    echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>';
                }
            } else if ($_POST['submit'] && $human != '4') {
                echo '<p>You answered the anti-spam question incorrectly!</p>';
            }
        } else {
            echo '<p>You need to fill in all fields!!</p>';
        }
    }
?>
```

I've already found some answers but none of which make any sense to me. I also tried inspecting the example on the tutorial's site but, ofcourse I can't access the PHP.

Can anybody explain this to me?

Comment: presumably this code above is some OTHER .php file than the one that contained the actual form? If that's the case, you'd need to combine the two so that the form gets re-displayed after you send your email, or you use this code to redirect BACK to the original page.

Comment: Well I have 1 separate php file containing my code and a HTML file. The tutorial file mentioned in the beginning that I should create a PHP file and put everything in there. But that didn't work at all so I tried it this way, and that did work.

Comment: I tested on my college servers by the way so I really have no control over their setup.

Comment: You can use wamp or xampp to run php scripts on your local machine. actually like your own web server :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the message on the same page then you have to put the php code on the same page like this:

```
<form method="post" action="">
          <label>Name</label>
          <input name="name" placeholder="John Doe">

          <label>Email</label>
          <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="john@doe.com">

          <label>Message</label>
          <textarea name="message" placeholder="Hello..."></textarea>

          <label id="antispam">What is 2+2? (Anti-spam)</label>
          <input id="antispambox" name="human" placeholder="4">

          <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['name'])&&!empty($_POST['email'])&&!empty($_POST['message'])&&!empty($_POST['human']))// check if everything has been filled out before doing anything else
{
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $from = 'From: TangledDemo';
    $to = 'contact@tangledindesign.com';
    $subject = 'Hello';
    $human = $_POST['human'];

    $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

    if ($_POST['submit']) {
        if ($name != '' && $email != '') {
            if ($human == '4') {
                if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {
                    echo '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>';
                } else {
                    echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>';
                }
            } else if ($_POST['submit'] && $human != '4') {
                echo '<p>You answered the anti-spam question incorrectly!</p>';
            }
        } else {
            echo '<p>You need to fill in all fields!!</p>';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: I wonder why this received a _-1_ since this is how it works in most cases. Anything else requires more complicated techniques such as AJAX, cookies or sessions (based on cookies). Only downside is that reloading the page after submitting will submit the form again (most browsers will show a related dialog).

Comment: true but other solutions are bit complicated as you sad and he is just learining php so for now i think this is enough

Comment: When user loads this page for the first time, there is not set $_POST array. So PHP will throw errors. those $_POST variables must be under `if($_POST['submit']){...` code block.
I think it may be reason to down voted, but i didn't downvoted this and i have no reputation to :)

Comment: Okay so what I didn't know was that I have to put everything in a PHP file, my HTML as well. That finally did the trick!

I would like to make use of the solution people suggested with AJAX but for now this will do.

Answer (score 0):

From what you appear to be asking you need to look into AJAX. You'll need to use a JavaScript library such as jQuery to make it easier. It will do exactly what you're looking for. Post the form data to your "contact.php" and the returned message (success/error) straight back to the page you are currently on. No redirect, no refresh.

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to go about this. AJAX is one of them, but since you are just starting out my opinion is to avoid that - learn the basics first. The code below is just that - the basics.

This method entails having the form and the processing on the same page. This is generally not the best method, but it is probably the simplest - and again, my opinion is that when you are starting out, simplicity is your friend.

*contact.php*

```
<?php
    // First, check if the submit button has been pressed - no processing occurs unless the form has been submitted. 
    // This is necessary because your $_POST variables do not exist until the form is submitted.
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        // The button has been pressed, so now gather data and set variables
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];
        $from = 'From: TangledDemo';
        $to = 'contact@tangledindesign.com';
        $subject = 'Hello';
        $human = $_POST['human'];
        $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

        // Now, validate and process
        if ($name != '' && $email != '') {
            if ($human == '4') {
                if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {
                    echo '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>';
                } else {
                    echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>';
                }
            } else {
                echo '<p>You answered the anti-spam question incorrectly!</p>';
            }
        } else {
            echo '<p>You need to fill in all fields!!</p>';
        }

    }
?>
 <form method="post" action="contact.php">
   <label>Name</label>
   <input name="name" placeholder="John Doe">

   <label>Email</label>
   <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="john@doe.com">

   <label>Message</label>
   <textarea name="message" placeholder="Hello..."></textarea>

   <label id="antispam">What is 2+2? (Anti-spam)</label>
   <input id="antispambox" name="human" placeholder="4">

   <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
 </form>
```

Keep in mind that, while this method works, in the long run it is not the best approach. It is better to keep logic and markup separate. That would mean having at least two pages - one that displays the form, and another page that processes the form. Even better approaches will involve object oriented programming. However, I am a firm believer in the *ready, fire, aim* methodology... when you are trying to learn, get it to work first, worry about best practices and optimization later. As you run into bigger problems and the need for more complexity arises, you can make adjustments and figure out better ways to do things. Progress only comes from practice, trial, and error. Good luck.